# Best way to model JSON data in python

Tags: python-3.x

This question may be opinion based, but I figured I'd give it shot.

I am attempting to create a variety of classes which gets its values from JSON data. The JSON data is not under my control so I have to parse the data and select the values I want. My current implementation subclasses UserDict from python3's collection module. However, I have had iterations where I have directly created attributes and set the values to the parsed data.

The reason I changed to using the UserDict is the ease of using the update function.

However, I feel odd calling the object and using `MyClass['attribute']` rather than `MyClass.attribute`

Is there a more pythonic way to model this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% convinced that this makes sense, but you could try this:

```
class MyClass (object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key in kwargs.keys():
            setattr(self, key, kwargs[key])

my_json = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}

my_instance = MyClass(**my_json)

print (my_instance.a)
# 1
print (my_instance.b)
# 2
print (my_instance.c)
# 3
```

--- edit

in case you have nested data you could also try this:

```
class MyClass (object):
     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
         for key in kwargs.keys():
              if isinstance(kwargs[key],dict):
                  setattr(self, key, MyClass(**kwargs[key]))
              else:
                  setattr(self, key, kwargs[key])

my_json = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":{"d":3}}

my_instance = MyClass(**my_json)

print (my_instance.a)
# 1
print (my_instance.b)
# 2
print (my_instance.c.d)
# 3
```

Comment: For nested data it would return a dictionary. You could also create new classes for each nested object. See my edited answer above.

Comment: `isinstance(kwargs[key],dict)` still doesn't capture arrays, but this is going in a good direction. There's also the problem of checking the type of value (`isinstance(myinstance.a, int)`) - this could develop into an actual library.

Comment: Yep, I think I stop here. You should get the point and can go from here. I am still not convinced that this all makes sense. If you don't know the structure of you json, why create a class? If schemas of different json objects differ, you would end up with two class instances with different interfaces.

Comment: Essentially I'm modeling sports data. I know what exact data I'm getting, it just has data that I don't need to hang on to. I just meant that I can't change the structure so I have to manually parse the JSON. Different classes hold different data. For example I have a class that models just a game's overall stats i.e. team names, score and that's it. I have another class that models the full statistics of a game.